# Apache server - not loading localhost

Tags: apache, localhost, listen, port80

I had this problem with my Apache server not starting, because port 80 was being used by some other program, I changed the 'Listen' port number to 8888 and the server got started. But now the problem is, when I try to access 'http://localhost/' from my browser its not finding it. Can anyone let me know whats the problem here, and resolution for the same ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your browser is defaulting to port 80 if no port is specified.

Try http://localhost:8888

Comment: thanks... I understood it was a stupid question... :)

Answer (score 5):

If you'd like to have apache listen on a port other than the default, you can do the following:

```
Edit ports.conf
nano /etc/apache2/ports.conf

Add a Listen directive
Listen default port
Listen 8888

Restart Apache
/etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

Answer (score 4):

When you type "http://localhost/" in your webbrowser it automatically thinks you mean port 80 (default HTTP port). If you have changed the server port t o 8888 you need to mention this when typing in the URL like so: "http://localhost:8888" or alternatively "http://127.0.0.1:8888".